# How can I get a map value inside a array from Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have the above data structure stored in Cloud Firestore. I want to save the fleets which is an array of maps with "id" and "name" stored in Firestore. I have difficulty in getting the data and stored as an array. I am just able to get a weird string but any method to store as a string array? Below is the code I used.

```
public void getFleets() {

    DocumentReference document = mDb
            .collection(FirestoreService.CLIENT_COLLECTION)
            .document(new SessionService(getApplicationContext()).getClientUID());

    document.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    List<String> group = (List<String>) doc.get("fleets");
                    Log.i(TAG, "getFleets: " + group);

                } else
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            });
}
```

This is the array result:

```
[{name=Caminhão, id=1}, {name=Escavadeira, id=2}, {name=Carregadeira, id=3}, {name=Trator, id=4}]
```

Comment: You can also directly [map an array of objects to a List of objects](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your `fleets` field is an array of maps.  What you're seeing in the debug output is exactly what I'd expect.  Note the outer square brackets indicate a java List type object, and the inner curly braces indicate java Map type objects inside it.  However, your generic type is wrong.  Instead of `List<String>`, you should use `List<Map<String, Object>>` to account for the Map objects in the List.

If you want a `List<String>` instead, you're going to have to write some code to pull the desired string out of the Map and build a new List using that value.  So, if you wanted the `name` property out of each map item, you could do something like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> groups = (List<Map<String, Object>>) doc.get("fleets");
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, Object> group : groups) {
    String name = group.get("name");
    names.add(name);
}
```

Now you have a list of names from the maps in the list.